# Yii: Multiple order by conditions

Tags: php, yii

I am using CActiveDataprovider to show data from different tables. Now I am stuck with a problem. I have got two tables (items and categories) and they both have got priority_order columns and I need to show the data using order by both the columns.

For example: there are two categories and six items belonging to these categories:

- **Food (priority_order 1)**

  1. food_item1 (priority_order 1)
  2. fodd_item2 (priority_order 2)
  3. fodd_item3 (priority_order 3)
- **Drink (priority_order 2)**

  1. drink_item1 (priority_order 1)
  2. drink_item2 (priority_order 2)
  3. drink_item3 (priority_order 3)

Now I need to show the data in CGridView exactly as they are in above order. All the food items will come first and will be sorted by their priority_order and drink items will come later; obviously in their order.

In `ItemsController` I am trying below code (for now order by categories only)

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Items', array(
                'criteria' => array(
                    'with' => array('category'),
                    'condition' => 'user_id=' . Yii::app()->user->id,
                    //'order' => 't.priority_order ASC',
                    'order' => 'category.priority_order ASC',
                ),
      ));
```

I would be happy to provide more details if still not clear enough. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just give second order by items ?

Comment: Does it work like that?? Wont that replace the first order statement and will order the dataprovider by items only??

Comment: No it won't. At least have a go.

Comment: sorry. that did work. was thinking it in different way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Items', array(
            'criteria' => array(
                'with' => array('category'),
                'condition' => 'user_id=' . Yii::app()->user->id,
                'order' => 'category.priority_order ASC, t.priority_order ASC',
            ),
  ));
```

Giving a second param to the order criteria should work

Comment: that was really easy. I was thinking for more complicated answer and didn't even consider this way