# Yii2: How to add two fields in orderby() of Find()

Tags: php, yii2

How to add more than one field to sort in find() method?

I have tried as below

```
$model::find()->orderBy([['id_date' => SORT_DESC],['item_no'=>SORT_ASC]);
```

But it is throwing error with query. 
Orderby Query produced by yii2 is: `ORDER BY 0, 1`

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497534/yii-multiple-order-by-conditions) might help you.

Comment: @Jurik I'm using find() function. not CActiveDataProvider. Also, I'm yii2.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#order-by):

```
$model::find()->orderBy([
  'id_date' => SORT_DESC,
  'item_no'=>SORT_ASC
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in the following code:

```
$model::find()->orderBy([['id_date' => SORT_DESC], ['item_no' => SORT_ASC]);
```

The correct way of doing this is:

```
$model::find()->orderBy(['id_date' => SORT_DESC, 'item_no' => SORT_ASC]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class NewsController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex ()
    {   $news = \common\models\News::find()->orderBy(['date' => SORT_DESC])->all();
        return $this->render("index",[
            'news' => $news
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: This does not answer the question (OP asked about 2 fields in `orderBy()`).