# Yii2: How to add two fields and NULLS LAST in orderby() of Find() using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830594/yii2-how-to-add-two-fields-in-orderby-of-find), but need to sort NULLS LAST for MySQL

something like...

```
$query->MODEL_NAME::find(); 
$query->orderBy(['column_1' => 'IS NULL','column_1'=> SORT_DESC]);
```

though this syntax is wrong. Thanks!

When I try `orderBy('column_1 IS NULL ASC, column_1 desc')` i get the error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column. The SQL being
>   executed was: `SELECT * FROM 'table' ORDER BY 'due_date IS NULL'`

NOTE: had to replace backticks with single quotes in the error above in order for it to display here.

Comment: You have two columns or two order by on same column? I don't see two columns in your query.

Comment: Just by ordering column_1 in ascending order, you will get desired result.

Comment: primarily two order by same column in this example, but can be multiple. Ie. sort b y column 1 nulls last, column 2, column 3 nulls last, etc...

Comment: I need in descending order since column_1 is a date in this case and want to show most recent

Comment: use `\yii\db\Expression`, I edited my answer

Comment: awesome... thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\yii\db\Expression`

```
MODEL::find()
    ->where('1')
    ->orderBy(
        [
            new \yii\db\Expression('col_1 IS NULL ASC, col_1 desc')
        ]
    )
    ->all();
```

Comment: That results in `ORDER BY `column_1 IS NULL ASC`. Instead of `ORDER BY `column_1` IS NULL ASC`

Comment: Note: `$model::find()` is wrong, use `MODEL_NAME::find()`

Comment: what? I didn't understand your comment

Comment: sorry... difficulty editing comment...That results in the "backtick" key in the wrong place and an error... `ORDER BY **column_1 IS NULL ASC** Instead of ORDER BY **column_1** IS NULL ASC`

Comment: Also, am using... MODEL_NAME::find(). I mis-spoke in orig question

Comment: I still don't get it, orderBy can get string parameter too. is my code working? what is the result?

Comment: don't use backticks here.

Comment: I updated my orig question to show the error I get and refined my example code. Its putting the backticks in the wrong place for the generated sql

Answer (score 0):

### Sort In Ascending Order With `NULLs` Last

#### Using The Minus Operator:

In MySQL, NULL values are considered lower in order than any non-NULL value, except if a - (minus) character is added before the column name while sorting.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM table     
ORDER BY -date_login DESC
```

**Using Yii framework**

```
Model::find()->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('-column_1 DESC')])->all();
```

#### Using The IS NULL Comparison Operator:

We can rely on the fact that IS NULL returns `1` when an expression is `NULL`, and `0` otherwise. With that information, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table     
ORDER BY column1 IS NULL, column1 ASC
```

**Using Yii framework**

```
Model::find()->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('column_1 IS NULL, column1 ASC')])->all();
```

#### Using COALESCE Function

The `COALESCE` function can also be used, which returns the first non-NULL value in a specified list of arguments (or `NULL` if there are no non-NULL values). Therefore, to sort `NULL` last whilst ordering non-NULL values in ascending order, we could simply supply the highest possible value as a fallback (or substitute) for `NULL` values.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY COALESCE(name, 'zz') ASC
```

This works because zee is the last letter in the alphabet, and by default, MySQL sorts symbols and numbers first and then alphabets. Therefore, substituting NULL values with the highest possible sequence of the letter zee pushes NULL values to the bottom of the list.

**Using Yii Framework**

```
Model::find()->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression("COALESCE(name, 'zz') ASC")])->all();
```

See [Here](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-order-null-values-first-or-last-in-mysql) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive response

Comment: what does the dash mean?

Comment: sorry @AlirezaFallah are you talking about the `-` operator that is used with the column name?

Comment: Yes, Exactly: `-`

Comment: its the minus operator, as i explained it in the first line,**`NULL` values are considered lower in order than any `non-NULL` value, except if a - (minus) character is added before the column name while sorting**